# How to filter issues resolved by me?

Tags: jira

I am using `Jira 6.1.4` and I would like to create a filter that shows either all the tickets that have been closed (resolved/fixed) by me or at least all the tickets that have ever been assigned to me. I tried various things out of Google but none helped.

Answer (score 0):

Using 6.4.5, I can open the Issues tab and search:

```
assignee = <username> && status = resolved
```

Then I can click "Save As" to create a persistent filter.

Comment: but the assignee is not me anymore

Comment: Hmm, not sure if JIRA keeps track of historical assignees

Comment: it does when you use `was` instead of `is`

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly just resolved by me but close enough:

> assignee was "myuser@myemail.com"

Answer (score 0):

This query will exactly answer the question "shows either all the tickets that have been closed (resolved/fixed) by me". This assumes that "Resolved" and "Fixed" are the actual names of your statuses:

`status was in (Resolved, Fixed) by currentUser()`

I don't know for sure if this will work as far back as your (already EOL!) JIRA 6.1, but it definitely works on 7.0+.